# Python 3 type hinting for decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, type-hinting, python-typing

Consider the following code:

```
from typing import Callable, Any

TFunc = Callable[..., Any]

def get_authenticated_user(): return "John"

def require_auth() -> Callable[TFunc, TFunc]:
    def decorator(func: TFunc) -> TFunc:
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            user = get_authenticated_user()
            if user is None:
                raise Exception("Don't!")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@require_auth()
def foo(a: int) -> bool:
    return bool(a % 2)

foo(2)      # Type check OK
foo("no!")  # Type check failing as intended
```

This piece of code is working as intended. Now imagine I want to extend this, and instead of just executing `func(*args, **kwargs)` I want to inject the username in the arguments. Therefore, I modify the function signature.

```
from typing import Callable, Any

TFunc = Callable[..., Any]

def get_authenticated_user(): return "John"

def inject_user() -> Callable[TFunc, TFunc]:
    def decorator(func: TFunc) -> TFunc:
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            user = get_authenticated_user()
            if user is None:
                raise Exception("Don't!")
            return func(*args, user, **kwargs)  # <- call signature modified

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@inject_user()
def foo(a: int, username: str) -> bool:
    print(username)
    return bool(a % 2)


foo(2)      # Type check OK
foo("no!")  # Type check OK <---- UNEXPECTED
```

I can't figure out a correct way to type this. I know that on this example, decorated function and returned function should technically have the same signature (but even that is not detected).

Comment: Callable arguments are really hard to type; various proposals are floating around but currently, the only thing I can tell you is to continue to use `...`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I did not find anything, except some issues opened on GitHub suggesting adding typing such as `StarArg` and `StarKwarg`. I wonder if there was a solution in this very particular case, but I think there won't be any :(

Comment: You found the discussions the type hinting developers are conducting to improve this situation.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't use `Callable` to say anything about additional arguments; they are not generic. Your only option is to say that your decorator takes a `Callable` and that a different `Callable` is returned.

In your case you *can* nail down the return type with a typevar:

```
RT = TypeVar('RT')  # return type

def inject_user() -> Callable[[Callable[..., RT]], Callable[..., RT]]:
    def decorator(func: Callable[..., RT]) -> Callable[..., RT]:
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> RT:
            # ...
```

Even then the resulting decorated `foo()` function has a typing signature of `def (*Any, **Any) -> builtins.bool*` when you use `reveal_type()`.

Various proposals are currently being discussed to make `Callable` more flexible but those have not yet come to fruition. See

- [Allow variadic generics](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/193)
- [Proposal: Generalize `Callable` to be able to specify argument names and kinds](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/264)
- [TypeVar to represent a Callable's arguments](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3028)
- [Support function decorators excellently](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3157)

for some examples. The last one in that list is an umbrella ticket that includes your specific usecase, the decorator that alters the callable signature:

> ### Mess with the return type or with arguments
>
> For an arbitrary function you can't do this at all yet -- there isn't even a syntax. Here's me making up some syntax for it.

Answer (score 80):

[PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) was accepted after the accepted answer, and we now have `typing.ParamSpec` and `typing.Concatenate` in Python 3.10. With these variables, we can correctly type some decorators that manipulate positional parameters.

The code in question can be typed like this:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, Concatenate, TypeVar

Param = ParamSpec("Param")
RetType = TypeVar("RetType")

def get_authenticated_user()->str:
    return "John"

def inject_user() -> Callable[[Callable[Param, RetType]], Callable[Concatenate[str, Param], RetType]]:
    def decorator(func: Callable[Param, RetType]) -> Callable[Concatenate[str, Param], RetType]:
        def wrapper(user: str, *args:Param.args, **kwargs:Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
            user = get_authenticated_user()
            if user is None:
                raise Exception("Don't!")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@inject_user()
def foo(a: int) -> bool:
    return bool(a % 2)


reveal_type(foo)  #  # I: Revealed type is "def (builtins.str, a: builtins.int) -> builtins.bool"

foo("user", 2)  # Type check OK
foo("no!")  # E: Missing positional argument "a" in call to "foo"  [call-arg]
foo(3)  # # E: Missing positional argument "a" in call to "foo"  [call-arg] # E: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Now that support for this has landed in mypy & Python 3.10 I tried this out, but I get this error on the typing of the `Callable` declarations (`Param = ParamSpec("Param"); MyFunc = Callable[Param, RetType]`): mypy: `error: The first argument to Callable must be a list of types, parameter specification, or "..."`

Comment: There is a mistake in `Concatenate`, it should be `Concatenate[str, Param]`. `ParamSpec` has to come last.

Comment: The tracking mypy issue for PEP 612 support is now fixed and closed.

Comment: The wrapper function arguments still needed typing (in my case, at least) `def wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:`

Comment: Hmm… I can’t make the above work, with or without [strict](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-strict) mode  That’s mypy v1.7.1 with only default settings.

Comment: This works now, but it's tricky business. Mainly, it seems you can't use a TypeAlias (like `OriginalFunc`/`DecoratedFunc`) to reference a `TypeVar`, or mypy will not know what `RetType` refers to. As far as I've been able to tell, you have to write out the `Callable`s literally.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Pyright.

````py
from typing import Any, Callable, Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def typing_decorator(rtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[..., Callable[..., T]]:
    """
    Useful function to typing a previously decorated func.
    ```
    @typing_decorator(rtype = int)
    @my_decorator()
    def my_func(a, b, *c, **d):
        ...
    ```
    In Pyright the return typing of my_func will be int.
    """
    def decorator(function: Any) -> Any:
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator  # type: ignore
````

Answer (score -5):

The problem is solved using the `decohints` library:

```sh
pip install decohints
```

Here is how it will work with your code:

```py
from decohints import decohints


def get_authenticated_user():
    return "John"


@decohints
def inject_user():
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            user = get_authenticated_user()
            if user is None:
                raise Exception("Don't!")
            return func(*args, user, **kwargs)  # <- call signature modified

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@inject_user()
def foo(a: int, username: str) -> bool:
    print(username)
    return bool(a % 2)
```

If you type below `foo()` in PyCharm and wait, it will show `foo` function parameter hints `(a: int, username: str)`.

Here is a link to the `decohints` sources, there are also other options for solving this problem: https://github.com/gri-gus/decohints

Comment: To save people a click, here's the entire implementation of decohints:

`def decohints(decorator: Callable) -> Callable: return decorator`

Comment: @DavidRöthlisberger LOL