# How to declare a return type hint of a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-3.7, python-typing

Just as a curiosity, since typing is not mandatory in python yet. I have a class method decorator that in which I want to declare types, but the return type of a decorator is a function, how should I declare it?

The decorator:

```
def requires_permissions(permission_list: list) -> ????:
    def decorator(method: ????):
        def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
            # ... Do some operations and return the method
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060133/python-3-type-hinting-for-decorator

Comment: @Chris_Rands didn't find it in the stack overflow suggestion list when I was typing the question, thanks! I'll close this as duplicate