# How to type hint a return value for a function decorated to alter the function return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm writing a Python package which makes use of decorators to remove boilerplate code while introspecting the function to get the function name by default. Something like the following:

```py
def make_real_instance(func: Optional[Callable] = None,
                       *, func_name: Optional[str] = None):
    def make_wrapper(in_func):
        @functools.wraps(in_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal func_name
            # Use func_name if provided
            func_name = func_name or in_func.__name__
            # Construct params for new object from function and its inputs
            stuff = in_func(*args, **kwargs)
            # Process stuff commonly
            new_object = ObjectConstructor(processed_stuff, func_name)
            return new_object
        return wrapper

    if func:
        return make_wrapper(func)
    return make_wrapper
```

Now, I have the class like so:

```py
class ObjectConstructor:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        #do stuff

    @make_real_instance
    def add_foo(self, foo_length: float):
        stuff = ... # process the input for this method
        return stuff
```

The `@make_real_instance` decorator causes an invocation of the `add_foo` method of an instance of `ObjectConstructor` to return a *new* instance. However, the actual return type of the undecorated method is a tuple.

What I'd like to do is to annotate the method to type hint the return as an instance of `ObjectConstructor`. I.e., the line:

```py
        def add_foo(self, foo_length: float):
```

Would become (having imported `annotations` from `__future__`):

```py
        def add_foo(self, foo_length: float): -> ObjectConstructor
```

However, my IDE (PyCharm, though I don't necessarily think of that as material in this case) complains (fairly, I suppose) that the output of this method doesn't match hinted return type.

Finally, my question: is there a way to correctly type hint a return type of a function call that you modify the output of using a decorator? Or is my only recourse to change my decorator to a function that I invoke in every function that I've decorated, and explicitly pass my `func_name` parameter each time? By which I mean something like:

```py
def make_obj_from_stuff(stuff, func_name) -> ObjectConstructor:
    # process stuff commonly
    new_object = new_object = ObjectConstructor(processed_stuff, func_name)
    return new_object

class ObjectConstructor:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        #do stuff

    def add_foo(self, foo_length: float) -> ObjectConstructor:
        stuff = ... # process the input
        new_obj = make_obj_from_stuff(stuff, "add_foo")
        return new_obj
```

If I want to maintain the decorator interface that I've created, do I just need to accept that I won't be able to correctly type hint without having my IDE complain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060133/python-3-type-hinting-for-decorator seems relevant.