# @property decorator type hints

Tags: python, types, python-decorators, mypy

Can I somehow tell `mypy` the type of my getter (`salary`) ?

```
from typing import Any
class MyProperty:
    def __init__(self, getter) -> None:
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> Any:
        return self.getter(obj)

class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = 7400.5

    @MyProperty
    def salary(self) -> float:
        return self.x

def check(something: str) -> None:
    # should issue: ... incompatible type float; expected str
    pass

p = Person()
check(p.salary) # <----- Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Note that this is less ambitious than [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060133/python-3-type-hinting-for-decorator).

Comment: Interestingly enough, the standard `property`  decorator, exhibit the expected behaviour and allows mypy to croak about the incorrect type (*Expected type 'str', got 'float' instead*)

Answer (score 7):

You can use generics and annotate your functions correspondingly. So you basically define a TypeVar and annotate the function that should be decorated to return that type and also the **get** function to return that type.

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, Generic
T = TypeVar("T")

class MyProperty(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, getter: Callable[[Any], T]) -> None:
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> T:
        return self.getter(obj)

class Person:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = 7400.5

    @MyProperty
    def salary(self) -> float:
        return self.x
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not installed mypy and only use the  internal tools of PyCharm for type checking. I just meant that PyCharm showed no problem using your code while it correctly does when using the builtin `property` decorator. As you say that mypy catches this, I have deleted my previous comment, and will delete this one in a while.