# How to type-annotate a function that returns either a decorator, a context manager, or a custom object?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a library that allows users to add functionality to their tests.
The library can be used in three different ways:

```py
def test() -> None:
    with custom_functionality():
        print("test")

@custom_functionality
def test_deco() -> None:
    print("test_deco")


def test_manual() -> None:
    custom_func = custom_functionality()
    custom_func.start()
    print("test_manual")
    custom_func.stop()
```

This works because of the following logic inside my library:

```py
from typing import ContextManager, Any, Callable, Optional, TypeVar, Union
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec('P')
T = TypeVar('T')


class ContextDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func: Optional[Callable[P, T]] = None) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self) -> Union[Callable[P, T], T]:
        self.start()
        x = self.func()
        self.stop()
        return x

    def start(self) -> None:
        self.__enter__()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self.__exit__()

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args: Any) -> None:
        pass


def custom_functionality(func: Optional[Callable[P, T]] = None):
    if func:
        def wrapper() -> Callable[P, T]:
            context_deco = ContextDecorator(func)
            return context_deco()

        return wrapper
    else:
        return ContextDecorator()
```

My question: How do I annotate the return-type of the `custom_functionality`-function?

As far as I can tell, there are three return-types here:

- `Callable[[], Callable[P, T]]`, because of the standard decorator
- `Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]` for the context manager
- `ContextDecorator` to ensure the `start` and `stop` methods are properly exposed/typed

A `Union` of the three doesn't work, because MyPy can't figure out when to use which.

**Note**: This code is a simplified version of what I need, but it works as is. The provided tests can be run with `pytest`.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your goal here, but it seems to me that you can just use `ContextDecorator` everywhere. It seems to function as all three. What do you need that `custom_functionality` function for?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I would have to force users to use `@ContextDecorator()` with parentheses. I'd prefer both options to be usable, so `@ContextDecorator` without parentheses as well

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290080/670693 ?

Comment: @BertBlommers No, you don't. Try it. `@ContextDecorator` on top of `def some_function(): ...` is equivalent to `some_function = ContextDecorator(some_function)`.

Comment: I think a bit more context (no pun intended) might be in order here. What is this construct actually supposed to _do_ in those three variants? Because it reminds me a lot of the pattern used by [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch), but there are a few weird things going on that I don't understand. Is the idea here that whatever function is provided by the user, first the `start` method is called, then the user's function, and finally the `stop` method? Because right now this implementation does not work this way.

Comment: Exactly - the execution should always be `start()` -> `user-method` -> `stop()`. This example code is actually a simplified version, believe it or not.. As provided, it does work though! Everything is there, if you copy everything in a single file (and add a print-statement to `__enter__` maybe), you can see it works as expected

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I think the reason `@ContextDecorator` can't be used here is because the OP is relying on some test discovery framework. `pytest`, for example, won't discover `ContextDecorator` objects by default as tests.

Comment: @BertBlommers OK, but what confuses me, is that in your usage examples, you only provide a user function in the decorator use-case (2nd example), but no user function in the context-manager (1st) and the simple initialization (3rd example) use-cases. I understand your examples here must be simplified. But you should not leave out _crucial_ pieces of functionality. It is unclear what you even expect to happen in examples 1) and 3). You said _"the execution should **always** be `start()` -> `user-method` -> `stop()`"_. Where is the `user-method` in those examples?

Comment: @dROOOze The provided code works with pytest

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Fair point - I should have said `start()` -> `user provided code` -> `stop()`. In the context manager example, all user provided code should be executed in between `start()` and `stop()`. Python actually creates a `Callable` with all inline code, and sends that to the context manager, as far as I'm aware

Comment: I've simplified the `ContextDecorator.__call__`-method a bit - it still exposes the problem, and is still runnable **as is**

Comment: It works with pytest because `wrapper` is discoverable by pytest. I believe that Daniil was suggesting that you ditch `custom_functionality` altogether and just use `ContextDecorator` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Optional, TypeVar, overload
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


class ContextDecorator(Generic[P, R]):
    func: Optional[Callable[P, R]]

    def __init__(self, func: Optional[Callable[P, R]] = None) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        if self.func is None:
            raise RuntimeError
        self.start()
        output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stop()
        return output

    def __enter__(self) -> ContextDecorator[P, R]:
        print("__enter__ called")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args: Any) -> None:
        print("__exit__ called")

    def start(self) -> ContextDecorator[P, R]:
        return self.__enter__()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self.__exit__()
```

```py
@overload
def context(func: Callable[P, R]) -> ContextDecorator[P, R]: ...


@overload
def context(func: None = None) -> ContextDecorator[Any, Any]: ...


def context(func: Optional[Callable[P, R]] = None) -> ContextDecorator[Any, Any]:
    return ContextDecorator(func)
```

Demo:

```py
def test() -> None:
    with context() as ctx:
        print(f"test with {ctx=}")


@context
def test_deco(i: int) -> None:
    print(f"test_deco({i=})")


def test_manual() -> None:
    ctx = context()
    ctx.start()
    print("test_manual")
    ctx.stop()


test()
test_deco(1)
test_manual()
```

Output:

```
__enter__ called
test with ctx=<__main__.ContextDecorator object at 0x...>
__exit__ called
__enter__ called
test_deco(i=1)
__exit__ called
__enter__ called
test_manual
__exit__ called
```

No complaints from `mypy --strict`.

Comment: That works indeed. I figured out I had to use overload, but I didn't know about `Generic`. Thank you Daniil!