# Python 3.10 type hinting for decorator to be used in a method

Tags: python, decorator, mypy, typing

I'm trying to use `typing.Concatenate` alongside `typing.ParamSpec` to type hint a decorator to be used by the methods of a class.  The decorator simply receives flags and only runs if the class has that flag as a member.  Code shown below:

```
import enum
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, Concatenate

P = ParamSpec("P")
Wrappable = Callable[Concatenate["Foo", P], None]

class Flag(enum.Enum):
    FLAG_1 = enum.auto()
    FLAG_2 = enum.auto()


def requires_flags(*flags: Flag) -> Callable[[Wrappable], Wrappable]:
    def wrap(func: Wrappable) -> Wrappable:
        def wrapped_f(foo: "Foo", *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
            if set(flags).issubset(foo.flags):
                func(foo, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, flags: set[Flag] | None = None) -> None:
        self.flags: set[Flag] = flags or set()
        super().__init__()

    @requires_flags(Flag.FLAG_1)
    def some_conditional_method(self, some_int: int):
        print(f"Number given: {some_int}")


Foo({Flag.FLAG_1}).some_conditional_method(1)  # prints "Number given: 1"
Foo({Flag.FLAG_2}).some_conditional_method(2)  # does not print anything
```

The point of using `Concatenate` here is that the first parameter of the decorated function must be an instance of `Foo`, which aligns with methods of Foo (for which the first parameter is `self`, an instance of `Foo`).  The rest of the parameters of the decorated function can be anything at all, hence allowing `*args` and `**kwargs`

mypy is failing the above code with the following:

```
error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, int], Any]"; expected "Callable[[Foo, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], None]"  [arg-type]
note: This is likely because "some_conditional_method of Foo" has named arguments: "self". Consider marking them positional-only
```

It's having an issue with the fact that at the call site, I'm not explicitly passing in an instance of `Foo` as the first argument (as I'm calling it as a method).  Is there a way that I can type this strictly and correctly?  Does the wrapper itself need to be defined within the class somehow so that it has access to `self` directly?

Note that if line 5 is updated to `Wrappable = Callable[P, None]` then mypy passes, but this is not as strict as it could be, as I'm trying to enforce in the type that it can only be used on methods of `Foo` (or free functions which receive a `Foo` as their first parameter).

Similarly, if I update `some_conditional_method` to be a free function rather than a method on `Foo`, then mypy also passes (this aligns with the linked SO question below).  In this case it is achieving the strictness that I'm after, but I really want to be able to apply this to methods, not just free functions (in fact, it doesn't need to apply to free functions at all).

This question is somewhat of an extension to [Python 3 type hinting for decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060133/python-3-type-hinting-for-decorator) but has the nuanced difference of the decorator needing to be used in a method.

To be clear, the difference between this and that question is that the following (as described in the linked question) works perfectly:

```
@requires_flags(Flag.FLAG_1)
def some_conditional_free_function(foo: Foo, some_int: int):
    print(f"Number given: {some_int}")

some_conditional_free_function(Foo({Flag.FLAG_1}), 1)  # prints "Number given: 1"
```

Comment: "This question is somewhat of an extension to Python 3 type hinting for decorator but has the nuanced difference of the decorator needing to be used in a method." - **why exactly should it matter** that the decorator will be used for a method? **What happens** when you try using the answers from that question, and **specifically how** does that not meet your needs?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I *am* using the answer from that question to the best of my ability.  But it fails type checking when decorating a method and calling that method (as opposed to decorating a free function and calling that, such as in the linked question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major issues here, and more detailed warnings would have been given if you had [`strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict) on:

1. Your type alias, `Wrappable = Callable[Concatenate["Foo", P], None]`, has a type variable (here, the `ParamSpec` `P`), but you're not providing the type variable when you're using the alias. This means you've lost all signature information after decorating with `@requires_flags(...)`. You can fix this by explicitly parameterising `Wrappable` with `P` upon usage:

   ```py
   def requires_flags(*flags: Flag) -> Callable[[Wrappable[P]], Wrappable[P]]:
       def wrap(func: Wrappable[P]) -> Wrappable[P]:
   ```

   This is caught with either `strict` mode or the mypy configuration setting [`disallow_any_generics = True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-any-generics).
2. The arguments to `Concatenate` consist of any number of [positional-only parameters](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) followed by a `ParamSpec`. The declaration

   ```py
   def wrapped_f(foo, *args, **kwargs): ...

   >>> wrapped_f(foo=Foo(), some_int=1)  # Works at runtime
   ```

   has now replaced `some_conditional_method` like so:

   ```py
   class Foo:
       @requires_flags(Flag.FLAG_1)
       def some_conditional_method(self, some_int) -> None: ...

   >>> Foo.some_conditional_method(foo=Foo(), some_int=1)  # Works at runtime
   ```

   This isn't great, especially if `some_conditional_method` is part of the public API. The type checker is warning you to write `wrapped_f` properly, by using a positional-only marker:

   ```py
   def wrapped_f(foo: "Foo", /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None: ...

   >>> Foo.some_conditional_method(foo=Foo(), some_int=1)  # Fails at runtime
   ```

   This is caught with either `strict` mode or the mypy configuration setting [`extra_checks = True`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-extra-checks).

The remaining minor issue is that `def some_conditional_method(self, some_int: int):` isn't annotated with a return type; this is a source of typing bugs if you're going to be using inheritance. I suggest getting into the habit of writing `-> None` for functions which don't return anything.

---

The fixed code can be re-run here: [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=76e750dad0ae7e7703194bb4214bc502)

Comment: This addresses all of the requirements I was after.  Nice one.  I was unaware of the positional-only marker.  I have used the keyword-only marker before but not that one.